# Find limit $\lim_{a\to 0} \, \frac{\left(a^{2 \varepsilon }-1\right) a^{x-\varepsilon }}{2 \varepsilon \log (a)}$

Tags: limits

I have tried to find this limit in Mathematica, with no success.

$$\lim_{a\to 0} \, \frac{\left(a^{2 \varepsilon }-1\right) a^{x-\varepsilon }}{2 \varepsilon  \log (a)}$$

Comment: @math are u sure? What if a tends to zero from below? then the second factor in the numerator becomes infinite...

Comment: @math also if $x-\varepsilon$ <0 the seond factor also becomes infinite, and I am exactly interested in the case $|x|<\varepsilon$...

Comment: @Arpan Banerjee counter-example: $x=1$, $\varepsilon$=2

Comment: You're correct, I didn't consider $a \to 0^-$.

Comment: @Anixx In that case, you can use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @Arpan Banerjee  logarithm is not differentiable at 0, L'Hopital's rule is not applicable

Comment: It is not $a=0$. It is $a \to 0$. In the latter case, L'Hopital's rule is applicable.

Comment: @Arpan Banerjee  we get infinity in both numerator and denomenator with this rule. If u know how to apply it properly, make an answer please.

Comment: You get $\frac{(x-\epsilon).a^{x-\epsilon-1}}{1/a} = (x-\epsilon).a^{x-\epsilon} = \infty$

Comment: @Anixx: Re your comment *"What if a tends to zero from below?"* – How do you define $\log a$ for $a < 0$?

Comment: @Martin R as $\log |a|$

Comment: @Anixx: And what about $a^{2\varepsilon} = \exp(2\varepsilon \log a)$ ? If you take $\log |a|$ here as well then the limits $a \to 0^-$ and $a \to 0^+$ are identical, as the expression is then symmetric.